# Using the same control instance in different views or windows

Tags: charts, mfc, controls

I have a (chart) control with huge data (x curves a ~10'000 points) inside. I need to show the control with same data in different views or windows.

Since speed and consistency matters (ca 150ms to redraw), I have tried use the same (read only) control instance in diffent views or windows.

This scheme seems to work:

```
void CMyview::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    ..
    if (NULL == m_pCurveTempCtrl)
    {
        m_pCurveTempCtrl = new CCurveCtrl;
        ..  
    }

void COtherView::OnActivateView(BOOL bActivate, CView* pActivateView, CView* pDeactiveView)
{
        CWnd* m_pCurveCtrl = Pointer to CMyView::m_pCurveCtrl;

        if (bActivate)
             m_pCurveCtrl->SetParent(pActivateView);
        else
             m_pCurveCtrl->SetParent(pDeactiveView);

        CFormViewEx::OnActivateView(bActivate, pActivateView, pDeactiveView);
}
```

But is this allowed?

Answer (score 1):

No. What happens if both view needs to be displayed? Only one will have a window...

The Doc View architecture is ideal for this.

Keep the data in the Document and use different views, that use the same data pool from the document.

Comment: Yes it is a Doc View architecture. 

But the data pool in Doc is incompatible with Control data pool. 
(std::vector vs CArray).

Comment: :) change it... Or better build a universal const accessor function into the Doc for  the array. No need to copy the data.

Comment: If copying data is slow. Don't do it. Seams that this is an XY problem ... ;)